# How can I format strings to query with mysqldb in Python?

Tags: python, string, mysql

How do I do this correctly:

I want to do a query like this:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM sometable 
                    order by %s %s 
                    limit %s, %s;"""
conn = app_globals.pool.connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query, (sortname, sortorder, limit1, limit2) ) 
results = cur.fetchall()
```

All works fine but the order by %s %s is not putting the strings in correctly. It is putting the two substitutions in with quotes around them.

So it ends up like:

```
ORDER BY 'somecol' 'DESC'
```

Which is wrong should be:

```
ORDER BY somecol DESC
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the answers. Will try out.

Answer (score 9):

> [paramstyle
>
>    Parameter placeholders can **only** be used to insert column values. They can **not** be used for other parts of SQL, such as table names, statements, etc.](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes)

Answer (score 6):

%s placeholders inside query string are reserved for parameters. %s in 'order by %s %s' are not parameters. You should make query string in 2 steps:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM sometable order by %s %s limit %%s, %%s;"""
query = query % ('somecol', 'DESC')
conn = app_globals.pool.connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query, (limit1, limit2) ) 
results = cur.fetchall()
```

DO NOT FORGET to filter first substitution to prevent SQL-injection possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Not all parts of an SQL query can be parametrized. The DESC keyword for example is not 
a parameter. Try

```
query = """SELECT * FROM sometable 
                    order by %s """ + sortorder + """
                    limit %s, %s"""

cur.execute(query, (sortname, limit1, limit2) )
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this alternatively...

```
query = """SELECT * FROM sometable 
                    order by {0} {1} 
                    limit {2}, {3};"""

sortname = 'somecol'
sortorder = 'DESC'
limit1 = 'limit1'
limit2 = 'limit2'

print(query.format(sortname, sortorder, limit1, limit2))
```

Comment: You should note that this will only work in >= python 2.6 -- which not everyone is using by now.

Comment: Also note that this is an incorrect solution for when the values are not controlled, due to the possibility of SQL injection attacks.