# Issue with inserting parameter values into MySQLdb.execute()

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

My code executes a query and then for each row in the result set tries to execute another query using values from that row.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
try:
    con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cccorder_uk');

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT code, name, box_size, commodity_code, country_of_origin FROM cccorder_uk.stocks")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            # split the code and take colour and size

            code = row[0].split('-')
            product_code = code[0]

            sql = """SELECT stock_groups.name FROM stock_groups_styles_map, stock_groups WHERE stock_groups_styles_map.style='%s'""" % (product_code,)

            cur.execute(sql)
            results = cur.fetchall()
            print results

except mdb.Error, e:

    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:    

    if con:    
        con.close()
```

When I print `results` I get an empty tuple, but if I hard code the `product_code`, for example `sql = """SELECT stock_groups.name FROM stock_groups_styles_map, stock_groups WHERE stock_groups_styles_map.style='EP22'"""`, this returns the results I expect.

Why is my code printing an empty tuple?

Comment: Put `print sql` after before the inner `cur.execute` or `print cur._executed` after it and post it, please

Comment: `
SELECT stock_groups.name FROM stock_groups_styles_map, stock_groups
    WHERE stock_groups_styles_map.style = 'EP01'`

Comment: When you hard code the `product_code`, where do you execute the query? In Python, using MySQLdb? Or in another environment, like Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's string-format operator `%` isn't smart enough to quote args for MySQL -- pass args to the database `execute` function, which will pass the args to MySQL correctly.

Example:

```
cur.execute("SELECT stock_groups.name FROM stock_groups_styles_map, stock_groups WHERE stock_groups_styles_map.style=%s", product_code)
```

See: [How can I format strings to query with mysqldb in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538311/how-can-i-format-strings-to-query-with-mysqldb-in-python)

Comment: @Korem: yes, *if* the variable is a string, *and* if it doesn't have quotes.  The database cursor is smart enough to quote anything, because it has additional information that Python doesn't have.

Comment: What I'm saying is that since in that particular case he already took care of quoting, your answer probably does not answer the question. Look at the query he posted in the comments - it's ok. Of course it's better to use execute, but that's not his problem.